# Php: Strlen() vs. count () Problems: Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, mysql, phone-number

I use these code to splite a Phone number String into area code and call number.

When i use "strlen($areacode)" i get a php warning strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

When is use count () instead of strlen(), the script is wrong execute. I get the result "No AreaCode found".

What make i wrong?

```
<?php
$phonenumber = '0349152023';
$link = mysqli_connect('host', 'DB', 'Pass','User') or die(mysqli_error());
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db( $link, 'DB');
$ErsteDrei = substr($phonenumber,0,3); 
$array = array();
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Areacode FROM `Areacodes` WHERE Vorwahl like '".$ErsteDrei."%' ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(Vorwahl) DESC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $array[] = $row;
}
foreach ($array as $areacode) {
    $subString = substr($phonenumber, 0, strlen($areacode));
    if ($subString == $areacode) {
        $phone = $subString." ".substr($phonenumber, strlen($areacode));
    }
}
if (!empty($phone)) {
    echo $phone;
}

else {
    echo "No AreaCode found.";
}
?>
```

Comment: if (empty($phone)) {
    echo "No AreaCode found.";
} I am not sure but try Like this.

Comment: `$row` is an array with 1 index, `$row['Areacode']`. So either assign it like that or access the index in the loop as needed `$areacode['Areacode']`.

Comment: do var_dump($array) to get  visibility on the structure and how to call elements within the array you are accessing; may help.

Comment: Read about [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) and [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php). They are different functions that have different purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that you are fetching the data as associative array "mysqli_fetch_assoc".
So each `$row` will actually be an array like this:

```
array("Areacode"=>"0349"); //or whatever the code is
```

You can do the following:

```
foreach ($array as $areacode) {
    $subString = substr($phonenumber, 0, strlen($areacode["areacode"]));
    if ($subString == $areacode) {
        $phone = $subString." ".substr($phonenumber, strlen($areacode));
    }
}
```

Or use "`mysqli_fetch_array`" instead of "`mysqli_fetch_assoc`"

Comment: Hope if it helped you would mark my answer is the solution :)